# Change of CSS property 'Display' to 'none' with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change 'Display' to 'none' with jQuery, but it doesn't work, or then i have wrote it wrong?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8q5g/5/)**

#### Code:

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul id="ul1">
      <p>News</p>
         <ul id="ul2">
             <p style="display:none">
                 Hey!, Whats up</p>

         </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(".menu").hover(function(){
  $(".menu ul ul").css("display", "block");
  $( ".menu ul ul" ).animate({width: 'toggle'});
});
```

I want to show the "ul2" when hovering on "menu", the animate part is working, i just need the css part to work, do i have done anything wrong?

They are working apart, but they aren't working together, i dont know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I only see animation here, where is your attempt to change the state of display attribute?

Comment: I think you posted the wrong jsfiddle?

Comment: there is no displays in your CSS, only animations

Comment: I can't link it, it keep saying that i has to be accompanied by code
Here is the link http://www.jsfiddle.net/Z8q5g/5

Comment: Right!   "has to be accompanied by code" means YOU NEED TO INCLUDE YOUR CODE HERE.    It's a rule on Stack Overflow.   Post any relevant code here, and we can take a look.

Comment: @Charlie74 It should do it now, now i got the link on too.

Answer (score 0):

With few modification here a new fiddle working:

```
$(".menu ul").hover(
    function() {
        $(".menu ul ul li").css("display", "block");
    }, function() {
       $(".menu ul ul li" ).css("display", "");
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/core972/h7y5T/1/

Comment: Take a look, http://jsfiddle.net/Z8q5g/8/ i dont know how to set these together, they are working apart, like .css and .animate, but i dont know how i should write it, with them both.

Comment: Look the fiddle I provided there are modifications in Html and CSS too.

Comment: it should be toggled, when hovering, i want to have preview of some news in there, so it should be hidden, then you hover, it will be toggled

Comment: Why use display block / display none when you have .show() and .hide() methods?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, and a lot cleaner you could use the following...

```
$(".menu ul").on("mouseenter", function() { 
     $(this).children().show();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
     $(this).children().hide();
});
```